# Separate Same Level Routes In Separate Route Files NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express

So instead of having my auth routes (register, login, etc) inside the main index.js route file, I'd like to have them separated like this:

```
routes
-- index.js
-- auth
  -- index.js
  -- login.js
  -- register.js
```

But I can't seem to get it work. I was thinking it would be like this:

```
// index.js
const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

router.use('/', function(req, res) {
  // if not logged in, redirect login else redirect to dashboard
  res.send("hello world");
});

require('./auth/index.js');

module.exports = router;
```

Then...

```
// auth/index.js
const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

router.use('/', require('./login.js'));
router.use('/', require('./register.js'));

module.exports = router;
```

Then...

```
// auth/login.js
const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

router.use('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Got here!");
  res.send("This is the login screen.")
});

module.exports = router;
```

But if I go to /login on my server, I just see hello world :(

Plenty of other posts but can't see how they organise code that exists on the same level since I'd like to have the end routes be

```
/
/login/
/register/
```

Not

```
/
/auth/login/
/auth/register/
```

Hope you understand where I am coming from.

Comment: I'm an idiot... I'm not actually creating the end routes properly. It's been too long of a day lol

Answer (score 0):

LESSON LEARNED:

Need to use app.route (or router.route in this case) to actually create a single end route.

app.use can be used to assign a function, or set of functions (group of routes in this case) to a path.

```
// index.js
const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

router.route("/")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    // if not logged in, redirect login else redirect to dashboard
    res.send("Hello World");
  })

router.use('/', require('./auth/index.js'));

module.exports = router;
```

AND...

```
// auth/login.js
const express = require('express'),
      router = express.Router();

router.route("/login")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.send("This is the login screen.")
  });

module.exports = router;
```